# Why isn't .class element {} overriding element {}?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to override styles

I tried different code. I delete cache and stopped creating static CSS files delivered from CDN.

```
.page-special article {
    background: none;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

.hentry .page-special {
    margin: 0;
}
```

I expected background image, padding, and margin to be erased but they still appear. The style-sheet is:

```
article {
    background: url(images/break.png) bottom center no-repeat;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
}
.hentry {
    margin: 0 0 4em;
}
```

Comment: `.hentry .page-special` and `.hentry` will not match the same element

Comment: Please add some html where you are apply these css classes.

Comment: The order that you load the stylesheets is relevant to specifity. Make sure you load the override stylesheet after the CDN stylesheet. Alternatively you could add `!important` at the end of your styles e.g. `background: none !important;` but it is much better practice to load the stylesheets in the correct order.

Comment: @Ahsan The html class selector appeared in the wrong tag. You are right!

Answer (score 0):

the first declartion is find the child 'articka of '.page-special:

```
.page-special article {
        background: none;
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }
```

The second one is find the child class .page-special of .hentry:

```
.hentry .page-special {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Then you are looking for any DOM element that is article and applying the following style:

```
article {
    background: url(images/break.png) bottom center no-repeat;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
}
```

Then you are declaring style to the class .hentry but before you were declaring style for the it's child class .page-special.

```
.hentry {
    margin: 0 0 4em;
}
```

In short, The first part your CSS declaration is pointing to the child of .hentry that is .page-special. Then you applied it to the parent. That is why you are not able to 'override' the style.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add the id to code in a style-sheet if selecting the class ".page-special" with html doesn't work. For example:

```
#id.hentry {
    margin: 0;
}
```